# How to get exact current latitude and longitude even without internet

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I am new to android. I want to develop an application in which i want to show only users current latitude and longitude even if internet is not connected. An app like this

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AndLocation.AndLocation&hl=en

I have tried the below code. the latitude and longitde changes if internet is connected. But if internet is not connected the latitude and longitude remains same if if i change my location. But another app i.e the above app from the link works well.. Please help me. How to do this.

This is my MainActivity

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
GPSTracker gps;
TextView lat1, long1;
Button exit, refresh;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private static MainActivity mInst;
double newLat, newLong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle("GPSFinder");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    lat1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    long1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRefresh);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    startAlarm();


    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enable
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                lat1.setText(""+latitude);
                long1.setText(""+longitude);

            }else{
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
        }
    });

    gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

    // check if GPS enabled
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        lat1.setText(""+latitude);
        long1.setText(""+longitude);

    }else{

        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }

}


public void startAlarm(){
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    /* Repeating on every 20 minutes interval */
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0,
            10 * 60 * 20, pendingIntent);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    // Other onResume() code here
    this.registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("some_unique_name"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    // Other onPause() code here

}
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Extract data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("lat");
        String msg2 = intent.getStringExtra("long");
      //  updateYourActivity(context);
        lat1.setText(""+message);
        long1.setText(""+msg2);
        Log.e("dfsfdsf", "" + message);
        Log.e("dsfdgdgdfgfd",""+msg2);
        //update the TextView
      //  Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Settttttttt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};


}
```

And this is GPSTracker class

```
  public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 5 minutes

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {

    if (locationManager != null) {
     //   if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
   // }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

 }
```

And AlarmReceiver class

```
  public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
GPSTracker gps;
double newLat, newLong;
String aString;
String bString;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    updateYourActivity(context);
}

private void updateYourActivity(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent("some_unique_name");

    // put whatever data you want to send, if any
    // intent.putExtra("message", message);

    gps = new GPSTracker(context);

    // check if GPS enabled
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

        newLat = gps.getLatitude();
        newLong = gps.getLongitude();

        aString = Double.toString(newLat);
        bString = Double.toString(newLong);
        // lat1.setText(""+latitude);
        //long1.setText(""+longitude);

    Log.e("new lat",""+aString);
        Log.e("new long",""+bString);
    }else{

        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }

    intent.putExtra("lat", aString);
    intent.putExtra("long", bString);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);

}

 }
```

I tried to update the latitude and longitude values constantly using alarm manager..

The application of which I provided the link shows location icon on status bar of device when application is running and after i exit application it is gone..

Please help me how to do this.

Comment: ok, so if my answer (that location was not null and onLocationChanged event) help you, please set it as accpet, thank you.

Comment: Did you read the previous comment? if you found other solutions, please create your own answer for this question and closed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the function GetLocation you should reset Location property at the beginning of code , because otherwise it wont get into a block of `if (location == null)` code acquisition from GPS

```
if (isGPSEnabled) {
            if (location == null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In the function `OnLocationChanged (Android.Locations.Location location)`, you should received new GPS position

```
    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
double lon = location.Longitude;
double lat = location.Latitude;

}
```

Comment: I update answer. With `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(` you start receiving GPS changes and then `onLocationChanged(Location location)` will be fired

Comment: Were you able to get a GPS location? Or have other problem?

Comment: I am getting gps location